# How can I make angle brackets function like lists?

Tags: custom-notation

Is there a way to make `<a,b,c>` behave like `{a,b,c}`, but remain displayed as `<a,b,c>` (short of setting up new rules for *every* operation involving such a list that I care about)?

Note: I've typed "<" and ">" here for readability, but really mean `\[LeftAngleBracket]` and `\[RightAngleBracket]`. That, way, I could write expressions that look like the normal vector-of-components notation that my intro physics students see in their textbook, but *Mathematica* would treat as the three-element lists that are the normal way to represent vectors (e.g., to distribute scalar multiplication, calculate dot and cross products, etc.).

I don't know where to start. The kinds of rules I've learned to define seem designed to *replace* one symbol with its equivalent, rather than simply *treating it as* its equivalent. I have a feeling this is easy, but it's a side of *Mathematica* I haven't learned about yet. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Notation` package is built for this.

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "x___", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"{", "x___", "}"}]]]
```

(It looks better when input via the Notation palette. Don't be frightened by the box manipulation - I used the palette to construct that expression.)

If you want to see exactly how it looks in the frontend, a cell which contains the expression above looks like:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "x___", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]", " ", 
    TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"{", "x___", "}"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}]], "Input"]
```

Comment: Aah, okay. It seemed like a common enough thing to want to do. When I took my first look at the Notation Package doc page, though the immediate reference to "constructing explicit MakeExpression and MakeBoxes rules" scared me away.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a particularly intuitive package. The docs tutorial under `Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation` is pretty good, though.

Comment: Wow, that solved my problem far more easily than I had expected. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this has an undesired side effect: It make _Mathematica_ use angle brackets instead of curly-braces for ALL lists. I'd like it to leave curly-braces as curly-braces, and angle-brackets as angle-brackets, but evaluate expressions involving angle-brackets as if they were curly-braces. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

One hacky possibility is the following:

```
f_[a___, AngleBracket[b__], c___] ^:= With[{r = f[a, List[b], c]},
    If[VectorQ[r],
        AngleBracket @@ r,
        r
    ]
]
```

Examples:

```
AngleBracket[1,2,3]^2
RandomInteger[1, {3, 3}] . AngleBracket[a, b, c]
```

> \[LeftAngleBracket]1, 4, 9\[RightAngleBracket]
>
> \[LeftAngleBracket]a + b, b, a + b + c\[RightAngleBracket]